# Is there a hotkey to loot everything in a container?

Tags: the-witcher-2

If you open a container to loot it, the mouse cursor is often far away from the "Take all" button. Is there a hotkey to loot everything in a container, or any other fast way to do that?

Comment: I am searching for that key, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! After opening a container you can press `space` to loot everything. However, if you're hovering over a specific item, pressing `space` will only loot that specific one.

Even more useful would be a way to loot in an area without having to open the containers, but I found no such thing.

Comment: /me slaps forehead. Tried Enter, Mouse1, Mouse2 (even Middle Mouse and Wheel up/down), all function keys and Escape.

Comment: To be fair, the little tutorial tip mentions this.